# C ++ (crypto ++) and C # encryption matching

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net-core, encryption, crypto++

For secure communication between client and server, I want to encrypt and decrypt data from both the client and the server, but I cannot get the same results, the data that comes from the client to the server is not decrypted, also when encrypting the same the same data from the server, I get a distinctive result from encryption on the client.

The client is written in C ++ using Crypto ++. The code:

```
string data = "teststring,teststring,teststring";
string encryptedData = client.encrypt(userData, "01234567891234560123456789123456", "0123456789123456");
```

```
string Client::encrypt(const string& str_in, const string& key, const string& iv)
{
    try {
        string str_out;
 
        AES::Encryption aesEncryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());
        CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption encryption(aesEncryption, (byte*)iv.c_str());
 
        StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
                new Base64Encoder(
                    new StringSink(str_out),
                    false
                )
            )
        );
        return str_out;
    }
    catch (exception e) {
        return "null";
    }
}
string Client::decrypt(const string& str_in, const string& key, const string& iv)
{
    try {
        string str_out;
        CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());
 
        StringSource decryptor(str_in, true,
            new Base64Decoder(
                new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
                    new StringSink(str_out)
                )
            )
        );
 
        return str_out;
    }
    catch (exception e) {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
data: "teststring,teststring,teststring"
encryptedData: "STpuD/dRgYard+Yqpdd5KOYET7607i7ZRUoKm5eshHzR3ErafaxgZ2+T1tSp0lWJ"
```

The server side of the code is written in C # (ASP.NET Core 3.1):

```
public static string Encrypt(string input)
{
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
 
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create("AES"))
    {
        // encryptor.BlockSize = 32;
        encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        encryptor.KeySize = 128;
        encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        encryptor.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("01286567891233460123456789123456");
        encryptor.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("0123456789123456");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            byte[] bt = ms.ToArray();
            input = Convert.ToBase64String(bt);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
 
public static string Decrypt(string input)
{
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
 
    using (Aes decryptor = Aes.Create("AES"))
    {
        //decryptor.BlockSize = 32;
        decryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        decryptor.KeySize = 128;
        decryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        decryptor.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("01234567891234560123456789123456");
        decryptor.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0123456789123456");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            byte[] bt = ms.ToArray();
            input = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bt);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Output:

```
data: "teststring,teststring,teststring"
encryptedData: "tIDlWnnzOQWh5HIvRDJya6z7jOglkIlYrICeYW9RoEM="
```

I cannot decrypt data from both the client and the server. Help me please.

Comment: Never mind how the encrypted data appears for a moment. Q: Do you get the same plaintext?  Are you able to encrypt in C# (regardless of what the encrypted data looks like) and successfully decrypt the expected plaintext using C++?  Are you able to encrypt in C++ and decrypt the expected plaintext in C#?

Comment: @paulsm4 Not. I am unable to decrypt data from client on server and vice versa. This is problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted C++ code is fine. It returns the posted ciphertext `STpu...0lWJ` on my machine and the ciphertext can be decrypted with the `decrypt()` method.

In contrast, although the posted C# code returns the posted ciphertext `tIDl...RoEM=`, the ciphertext cannot be decrypted using the `Decrypt()` method. This has two reasons:

- In the `Encrypt()` and in the `Decrypt()` method different keys are used. The key of the `Decrypt()` method matches the key applied in the C++ code. With regard to a comparison of the ciphertexts of both codes, the key in the `Encrypt()` method should be replaced.
- The ciphertext is Base64 encoded in the `Encrypt()` method, but not Base64 decoded in the `Decrypt()` method (but ASCII encoded instead). Here a Base64 decoding must be done in the `Decrypt()` method (note that an ASCII decoding in the `Encrypt()` method is not an alternative, since this would corrupt the ciphertext).

If these two bugs are fixed, the ciphertexts of C++ and C# code match except for the end. This last mismatch is caused by different paddings. In the C++ code PKCS7 padding is used, in the C# code Zero padding. If the padding in the C# code (in the `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` methods) is changed to `PaddingMode.PKCS7`, the ciphertexts match.

Other problems in the C# code are:

- In the `Encrypt()` method `Encoding.Default` is used, in the `Decrypt()` method `Encoding.ASCII`. Here a consistent encoding, e.g. `Encoding.UTF8` should be applied.
- The specified 128-bit key size is not consistent with the 256-bit key used. This has no effect because the explicit key specification automatically corrects the key size (nevertheless, the key size should be specified correctly or completely omitted).

Also, it should be noted that a static IV is insecure (for testing purposes, of course, that's OK).